# How do I query only rows where multiple instances with the same ID exist with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, count, where, aggregate-filter

I have a table where I want to gather some statistics, but only for items that are repeated two or more times. To simply, here is how the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id bigint,
    something text
);
```

Most rows have a unique `id`, some have repeated entries where `something` differs.

What I'm wondering is whether there is a way to read the table but only items that have 2 or more rows with the same `id`.

I know how to count the number of duplicated roes using the `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS count FROM test GROUP BY id;
```

I don't really see how to use the `COUNT(id)` in a `WHERE` or `FILTER` clause (since aggregate functions are not allowed there).

---

Just in case, a very small data sample would be:

```
 id | something
----|-----------
 1  | first
 2  | second
 2  | third
```

In the result I want to see:

```
 id | something
----|-----------
 2  | second
 2  | third
```

Comment: "some have repeated entries where something differs"  The something is required to differ because of a constraint, or you want to count cases only where they do differ, or you just happen to know that they differ but don't want to do anything about it?

Comment: @jjanes They are likely to differ. The constraint is over 5 columns, which is not represented here. But for what I'm trying to do here, we can consider that they always differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need some kind of subquery to do this, there is no "single-level" way to do it.

One way is with a window function.  This needs a subquery because there is no way to reference the wcount in the same level at which it was computed:

```
select id,something from (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by id) from test as wcount
) foo where wcount>1;
```

Another way is with a join to an aggregated subquery:

```
select * from test 
join 
(select id from test group by id having count(*) >1) foo
using (id);
```

An advantage of the second form is that you change `count(*)` to `count(distinct something)` if that is what you want to do, but that would produce an error if done in the window-function technique.

Another method would be with an EXISTS subquery, but that is slower in my hands:

```
select * from test 
where exists (
    select 1 from test t2 where t2.id=test.id and t2.something <> test.something
)
```

If you didn't want to force "something" to differ in order to count them, then you could resort to using the system column ctid in the <>.